# Appending columns/variables from a data frame into a new variable

Tags: r

I've been searching for how to do this but cannot seem to find an example for my questions. I'm pretty new to R but am very familiar with SAS, so I wanted to ask how to do the equivalent of this SAS code in R.

I have one dataset (cohort), and two variables (last_pre_cv_prob, first_post_cv_prob), and I want to make a new dataset that has two variables, the first of which is the two previous variables set underneath each other (cv_prob), the second is a variable indicating which variable the data came from (time). So in SAS I would simply do this:

```
data post_cv;
    set cohort(keep=last_pre_cv_prob rename=(last_pre_cv_prob=cv_prob) in=a)
    cohort(keep=first_post_cv_prob rename=(first_post_cv_prob=cv_prob) in=b);
    if b then time='post';
    if a then time='pre';
run;
```

How would I do this in R?

Thanks!

edit:

```
post_cv2 %>% gather(column, prob, last_pre_cv_prob, first_post_cv_prob)

Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'last_pre_cv_prob' not found
```

Then I tried:

```
post_cv2 %>% gather(column, prob, liver_cv$last_pre_cv_prob, 
liver_cv$first_post_cv_prob)

Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  liver_cv$last_pre_cv_prob
*  liver_cv$first_post_cv_prob
```

edit:

Second issue resolved, I had to add the little quote marks

```
post_cv2 <- post_cv %>% 
  gather(time, cv_prob, `liver_cv$last_pre_cv_prob`, 
`liver_cv$first_post_cv_prob`)
```

edit:

Solved!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

post_cv <- data_frame(pre = liver_cv$last_pre_cv_prob, post = liver_cv$first_post_cv_prob)

post_cv2 <- post_cv %>% 
  gather(time, cv_prob, pre, post)
```

Comment: `post_cv2  <- liver_cv %>% gather(column, prob, last_pre_cv_prob, 
first_post_cv_prob)`

Comment: What you want is take your current dataframe (`liver_cv`), pipe it (`%>%`) into the `gather` function, and store the results into a new dataframe called `post_cv2`

Comment: Okay, so I tried that but like before, it doesn't recognize the last and first variables if I use that, so I put in "liver_cv$" before each and then I get that integer column position error above

Comment: Okay I made some progress, but I'm also getting an error saying that it could not find the function "str_extract"

Comment: that comes from the `stringr`package  and should be loaded when you call `library(tidyverse)`. You can either install `stringr` and load it separately (`library(stringr)`) or you can switch that out with an `ifelse` statement similar to what you did in your SAS code

Comment: thanks, I put the working code in the OP

Comment: I can save you a step: when you create `post_cv`, name your columns:
`post_cv <- data_frame(pre = liver_cv$last_pre_cv_prob, post = liver_cv$first_post_cv_prob)`. Then in gather, you'd write `gather(time, cv_prob, pre, post)`. You could then skip the last mutate

Answer (score 2):

You can simply gather the 2 columns and extract the time information:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cohort <- data_frame(last_pre_cv_prob = runif(5),
                     first_post_cv_prob = runif(5))

cohort_2 <- cohort %>% 
  gather(time, cv_prob, last_pre_cv_prob, first_post_cv_prob) %>%
  mutate(time = str_extract(time, "post|pre"))

cohort_2
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>     time    cv_prob
#>    <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1    pre 0.64527372
#> 2    pre 0.55086818
#> 3    pre 0.05882369
#> 4    pre 0.19626147
#> 5    pre 0.05933594
#> 6   post 0.25564350
#> 7   post 0.01908338
#> 8   post 0.84901506
#> 9   post 0.07761842
#> 10  post 0.29019190
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume I remove the " = runif(10)" part? Is that just for display purposes?

Comment: exactly. That part was just to create a sample dataframe